# For a GA4 property connected to UA, do I have to change the code on the website from UA- to G-ZZZ

Tags: google-analytics, migration, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

I'm a frontend dev tasked often with the "send instructions" link from GA, that contains >no< info whatsoever for which property or website is it about :D

What I can't find in here, or in the 12 pages of google documentation I've read, is the part of "reusable code". Right now, the migration process is basically creating a GA4 property and linking it to UA, right? And it starts working. Great. But the implementation I've been given is still a gtag + UA-ZZZ. Question is: after the six-months grace period following 01.07.2023, will I have to also change the UA-ZZZ to G-ZZZ, or will the gtag continue working with the UA-key, although GA3(UA) will not receive/process data anymore?

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing the Google tag (gtag.js) manually, the GA4 property you create will have the measurement/tracking ID in the format of G-XXXXXXXXXX instead of UA-#########. After July 1, 2023, Google will stop processing new data for your Universal Analytics property so you will need to ensure that your sites and pages are setup with the new tag.

If you navigate to your GA4 property > Admin > Data Streams > View tag instructions > Install manually tab, you will see that the config includes the new GA4 tag in the format of G-XXXXXXXXXX.

Comment: Not my question at all.  

I have a website with UA-#####. 
I have connected the UA property with the newly created GA4 property. 
It's 2024. Do I still have/receive data or not?

Comment: @MarinHTML - It is my understanding that even when 'linked' once the grace period is over, anyone using the UA ID will cease to have any data collected. So I would assume that in 2024, you will not receive any data unless you have switched over to gtag fully.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now, the migration process is basically creating a GA4 property and linking it to UA, right?

Not quite. This is not exactly a migration. It just automatically casts UA's data structure into GA4/Firebase format. Which may be good enough for how easy it is. Google has an array of articles describing the proper migration process on many levels [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10759417?hl=en)

Yes, it will likely continue since that pseudo UA property has all the limitations of GA4 and none of the freedoms of UA, which is the main point of the global UA -> GA4 migration: GA4 is a lot cheaper to maintain for Google. Very short data retention, simplified definitions of complex concepts, harsher sampling, etc. Moreover, Google never misses a chance to indicate that UA is being deprecated. And it doesn't do so when you make the property in the GA4 context.

This is a hack, however. A hack, supported by google, but still a hack. While using it, you can only use those tracking features that are similar in both, UA and GA4. But if your analysts are ok with it, it's fine. It's not like GA4 brings a lot to web tracking.

Tracking best practices wouldn't typically require the front-end devs to ever touch gtag(), it instead offers dataLayer as an abstraction layer between front-end and analytics. So the front-end would .push() events and payloads to the window.dataLayer array. The rest would be done by analysts from GTM since GTM overrides dataLayer's push() method to be able to immediately react to every push.

Now, with a system like that, about 100% of front-end code is reusable and this migration doesn't affect front-end at all since now all remapping can be effectively done withing GTM. And for the more complex things like EEC, there are now multiple GTM templates able to translate UA's EEC dataLayer events into GA4's format.